# Get if linked succefully shared with google plus share button

Tags: google-plus

I need to get if a url is succefully shared in google plus. Note that is not enough if the user clicks in the share button and then closes the bubble. I need to know for sure that the link is shared to exeucte a certain logic in my app.

Is tehre any wy to do this? Any filed in the "url" parameter of the `onend interaction` function I need to look for?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample demonstrating how you can use `onendinteraction` with the Google+ share button.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function startInteraction(params) {        
            window.console.log('end interaction');
        };

        function endInteraction(params) {
            window.console.log('end interaction');
        };
</script>

<g:plus action="share" href="http://example.com" onstartinteraction="startInteraction" onendinteraction="endInteraction"></g:plus>
```